# how to parse the HTML string query

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Validate input from untrusted sources before it is used. The untrusted data sources may include HTTP requests, file systems,

```
var string = `<div id="myNode" data-foo="{id:1, name:'something'}"></div>`;

const item = $(string).data("foo");
```

how can we fix this I did try with const `item = $(jQuery.parseHTML(string)).data("foo");`

It doesn't work can anyone please help here.

Comment: Fix what exactly?  Your code [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/ym5hw7ez/) - if you're expecting `item` to have any meaning then `data-foo` will need to be valid JSON - it's not right now - compare `var item = { id:1, name:'something' }; console.log(JSON.stringify(item))` - with valid JSON: https://jsfiddle.net/ym5hw7ez/1/

Comment: What if  data-foo="{id:1, name:'something'}"></div> is in double quote as it is ? https://jsfiddle.net/kfetvrz0/1/

Comment: Use single quotes for `data-for='`  If you have double quotes inside double quotes, then you don't have valid HTML  `data-for="{"id":1}"` is `data-for="{"` then some other attribute `id":1`

Comment: In case we have no control to update the html then ? is there any way we can replace double quote to single quote tried string.replace but doesn't work

Comment: If you have no control to update the html then you have no way to generate valid HTML / valid JSON.